# Wrong format geometry field geojson

Tags: django, geolocation, django-rest-framework, gis, geojson

I'm using *rest_framework_gis* *GeoFeatureModelSerializer* and I have this property in the class that I want to serialize:

```
the_geom = models.PointField(('Point'), null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
```

The serializer:

```
class Serializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PointOfInterest
        id_field = False
        fields = settings.FEATURE_FIELDS_TO_SERIALIZE
        geo_field = "the_geom"
```

The problem is that returns a geojson with poorly formatted geometry field, like this:

```
geometry: "SRID=4326;POINT (-8.3093807187199999 41.4384913111000017)",
```

Comment: Have you added `rest_framework_gis` to installed apps?